# No COM1 port on hyper-v

Tags: kernel, hyper-v, debug, com

I just made a fresh Windows 8.1 install and am trying to set-up a VM for kernel debugging. Therefore, I need to create a serial link to debug the VM using windbg.

Usually I just simply add a new COM port and use it as a named pipe. However, I can't find any way to add this hardware. There is nothing relevant on the "add hardware list".

What do I need to install this port then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2013/10/31/hyper-v-generation-2-virtual-machines-part-5.aspx

Comment: I eventually find out my problem. 

If you directly indicate an ISO file when creating the VM, everything is going to be OK. 

However, when you just select the "install later" option and install by hand, no COM port is going to show up.

The solution above seems okay. I first thought I didn't even have a COM port so I didn't try it out. 

Thanks ;)